# Running a powershell script through Psexec

Tags: powershell, psexec

new to the forum.
I've been trying to run a PowerShell script from sccm package via psexec command but can't seem to get it to work, possibly been asked before but I give it a go here. not sure if its pathway issues, permission issues or other input issues.

Tried running this:

```
psexec -i \\server\packages$\app\folder with space\deploy-script.ps1
```

This gives the error:

> "couldn't access server\packages$\app\folder with space" 
>   
> "Connecting
>   to server..."

Tried to put "pathway" as well but also doesn't work.
I've been running this with admin elevated rights still no go.

```
psexec -i \\server\packages$\app\folder with space\deploy-script.ps1
```

Initiates script installation.

Comment: You should quote the path `"PATH"` and if this is supposed to be a UNC path, you need two backslashes at the beginning, so  `"\\server\packages$\app\folder with space\deploy-script.ps1"`

Comment: Apologies if this is off-topic, but to be honest, I'd rather use ```Invoke-Command```, if possible. I don't know if you have the option, but if you do, it's easier (you don't need PSExec) and output/ logging can be more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Check the syntax of psexec here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

The correct systax for your command should look something like:

```
psexec \\server powershell.exe -f "\\path\to\script.ps1"
```